# CSS flexible layout scroll issue on webkit based browsers (Chrome and Safari)

Tags: css, google-chrome, layout

I am using css flexible vertical layout which contains two div elements. I want the first element to be frozen and second element to show vertical scroll bar only if its content grow bigger than available height.

I have managed to achieve it with a small problem. In webkit based browsers like Google Chrome and Safari the second div element always show vertical scroll bar. 
Please refer code at http://jsfiddle.net/psdzr/5/

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
html,body{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    overflow:hidden;
    height: 100%;
    width:100%;
}

.sapMFlexItem {
  position: relative;
}

.sapMFlexBox{
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    display:flex;
    flex-direction:column;
 }

 div#mydiv { height: 100%; }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="sapMFlexBox" style="background-color:red">
 <div class="sapMFlexItem">One</div>
  <div class="sapMFlexItem" style="height:100%; overflow:auto">
   <div id="mydiv" style="background-color: green;">Hello</div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

It works as expected in Internet Explorer and FireFox.

Any idea how to get rid of the vertical scroll bar when it's not required.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `overflow-y: auto;` to make the vertical scrollbar appear only when it needs to. I have a fiddle here that, based on my assumptions, is doing what you want. I added an additional class that provides a full height minus the header, using `calc()`, and has `overflow-y: auto` set to it.

**CSS**

```
html,body{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    overflow:hidden;
    height: 100%;
    width:100%;
}

.sapMFlexItem {
  position: relative;
}

.sapMFlexBox{
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    display:flex;
    flex-direction:column;
 }   

.sapMFlexItem-scroll {
    background: #ddd;
    overflow-y: auto;
    height: calc(100% - 20px);
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="sapMFlexBox" style="background-color:red">
 <div class="sapMFlexItem">Item frozen</div>
 <div class="sapMFlexItem sapMFlexItem-scroll">
   Urna augue auctor, facilisis egestas et a est, hac sit lectus, vel dis facilisis duis urna sed! Magna augue pulvinar massa sit lundium scelerisque ut, adipiscing arcu, nec, tincidunt. Tincidunt! Ac, mattis etiam sagittis dolor phasellus! Dapibus porta, dignissim et magna elementum magna sit sociis dolor magnis in? Quis tortor? Nunc parturient. Ut proin mauris, tincidunt, rhoncus ut augue aliquet? Enim facilisis adipiscing, platea pid. Sit? Lectus vel ut elit lectus sagittis a lundium, vel. Urna turpis rhoncus sed ultrices dignissim velit penatibus tincidunt vel elementum amet lorem egestas mid tortor, duis etiam tortor aliquam? Sit lorem cursus integer velit.

Sed, pulvinar tincidunt, elementum! Sociis ac porttitor est in, adipiscing lectus, nisi turpis. Dapibus purus elementum elementum, nec, augue? Odio magna purus massa, scelerisque odio, risus sit. Tincidunt turpis rhoncus cum etiam, augue massa, et rhoncus aliquam, in vel? Mus augue, aliquam urna, in nisi magna tempor cum cras. Cursus vel augue porttitor! Aliquam nec risus nunc et in. Elit rhoncus, magna enim pellentesque, et magna dolor turpis natoque sagittis lacus! Porttitor dis platea proin! Vel etiam pid habitasse! Cum! Dictumst tristique integer massa penatibus mattis duis sit enim, et porta, aliquet pulvinar pellentesque porta! Amet nascetur, urna pellentesque.

Etiam sagittis ut! Urna aliquam tortor auctor? Natoque! Massa. Integer amet hac adipiscing rhoncus a, nec! Urna rhoncus vel eros tempor a ac sociis, non turpis odio lundium pulvinar aliquam lundium adipiscing arcu diam. Hac augue elementum porttitor vel, parturient massa elit proin vel cras? Vel! Lacus ac integer, in elementum! Scelerisque. Lacus? Ultrices pid, urna quis, duis ultricies! Eros, cras urna enim. Proin lectus turpis? Nunc sociis adipiscing. Ac sed, turpis turpis sagittis lectus tristique! Hac, in sociis tincidunt natoque urna? Turpis rhoncus. Augue adipiscing platea! Tempor lectus massa nunc mus odio porttitor mattis a sociis amet, ac.

Hac etiam diam. Turpis dapibus non ut enim augue aenean montes, scelerisque ut urna mid ac scelerisque pulvinar tortor velit adipiscing. Velit diam, a porttitor magna hac pulvinar purus! Magna hac. Hac turpis purus aenean. Non phasellus turpis? Nisi mus ac, et integer turpis ac dis et auctor dapibus. Porttitor tincidunt. Tincidunt porttitor scelerisque odio odio placerat! Turpis tortor platea mattis egestas magna, mattis turpis. Phasellus nec, odio lorem, in dapibus mauris sit sed, parturient aliquet. Aenean. Dignissim, penatibus aliquam vel aenean porta urna, proin ac platea vel sit diam, penatibus, non nunc adipiscing dis augue turpis ac augue.

Magnis cursus a, pulvinar sed integer vut sit sed vut urna aenean sed nascetur in, aenean! Placerat facilisis natoque mus tincidunt non elementum lectus! Elementum dapibus augue aenean ultrices lacus odio? Porta? Dis nec, penatibus pulvinar rhoncus! Penatibus rhoncus, lectus in, mus mus, nascetur! Sed integer odio, enim dapibus nunc aenean, dictumst urna ultricies magna adipiscing duis enim lacus integer scelerisque dis est lundium aliquam lectus ut scelerisque ut enim habitasse sagittis urna, amet nec! Velit quis pellentesque integer. Sagittis dignissim augue lundium. Ut cursus placerat sit, adipiscing ac. In nec lectus adipiscing? Augue nec sed, cum augue vel.
  </div>
</div>
```

**[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/psdzr/6/)**

**UPDATE**

It makes more sense to use `height: 100%;` instead of `calc()`, so you can refer to the HTML and CSS in this [**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/psdzr/11/).

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. But that didn't help. http://jsfiddle.net/psdzr/7/ 
In my JSFiddle example I have a div element nested inside the 'scrollable' div.

Comment: About calculating the height using <code>calc(100% - 20px);</code> that works for this sample but height of frozen element is not fixed. It can vary.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're looking for then. What should span across the entire area? The `div`? Here is another fiddle that has less content, and no scrollbar. http://jsfiddle.net/psdzr/9/

Comment: Not sure if you noticed, but I removed all your inline styles from this fiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/psdzr/7/). The `<div style="height: 100%;">` was the issue. It is making that container too tall, therefore triggering the scrollbar. If you delete that inline style, it works as you've wanted.

Comment: I changed your fiddle and I get the scroll bars back. http://jsfiddle.net/psdzr/10/

Comment: Also, for your comment about `calc()`, I realize this. You can also use `height: 100%;`. After I did that fiddle, I realized I could have used 100% and it worked just fine.

Comment: I don't think you're getting the idea here. On `line 4` of this fiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/psdzr/10/), you have the code `<div style="height: 100%;">`, which is what is causing the scrollbar. If you remove that inline style, you won't have a scrollbar. here's an updated fiddle with that inline style removed. viola, no scrollbars. http://jsfiddle.net/psdzr/11/

Comment: Even removing inline styles is not helping if the nested element height of 'scrollable' div is 100%. http://jsfiddle.net/psdzr/13/

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish by setting a height to the nested div? Your question is still to have a y scrollbar show only when content exceeds the height of the parent container, right? I'm not sure why you're wrapping the text in a div either.

Comment: I am looking to implement a generic layout which contains a frozen element and scrollable element which occupies all the remaining screen. The text in scrollable div is just an example. The scrollable div should take any content. I don't understand why the scrollable div shows scrollbars when its netsted element has 100% height. That too only in WebKit based browsers. I hope I am making sense.